# Make width of div not reach the end of the page

Tags: html, css

So I am making a Flask web app and I have a nav bar. The background color of this navbar reaches to both horizontal ends of the page. How could I change this so that the background color is only behind the content? Any help would be much appreciated.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'css/base.css')}}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" type="image/x-icon">
{% block head %}{% endblock %}    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navBar">
        <div id="flex-container">
            <button class = "navButton" onclick = "window.location.href='main'">Main Page</button>
            <button class = "navButton" onclick = "window.location.href='user'">User</button>
        
            <button class = "logIO navButton" onclick = "window.location.href='login'"">Login</button>
            <button  class = "logIO navButton" onclick = "window.location.href='logout'">Logout</button>
        
            
           
            
        </div>
    </div>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html{
    background-color: thistle;
}
.navBar{
    background-color: darkslategrey;
}
#flex-container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-radius: 13px;
    position:relative;
}   
.navButton {
    padding:10px 20px;
    margin:8px;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: rgb(133, 131, 131) 3px 3px;
    
}
.navButton:hover{
    box-shadow: rgb(104, 101, 101) 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to do?

I simply added this code to your navbar:

```
display: block; <!--convert div to block element-->
max-width: 90%; <!--make div 90% width of container -->
margin: 0 auto; <!--center the div -->
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html{
    background-color: thistle;
}
.navBar{
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
max-width: 90%;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
}
#flex-container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-radius: 13px;
    position:relative;
}   
.navButton {
    padding:10px 20px;
    margin:8px;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: rgb(133, 131, 131) 3px 3px;
    
}
.navButton:hover{
    box-shadow: rgb(104, 101, 101) 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'css/base.css')}}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" type="image/x-icon">
{% block head %}{% endblock %}    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navBar">
        <div id="flex-container">
            <button class = "navButton" onclick = "window.location.href='main'">Main Page</button>
            <button class = "navButton" onclick = "window.location.href='user'">User</button>
        
            <button class = "logIO navButton" onclick = "window.location.href='login'"">Login</button>
            <button  class = "logIO navButton" onclick = "window.location.href='logout'">Logout</button>
        
            
           
            
        </div>
    </div>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```